# Count string length in byte using mb_strlen in php

Tags: php

I got a trouble while using mb_strlen function.

`mb_strlen('１２', 'SHIFT-JIS')` got 4 (full width char)

`mb_strlen('12`', 'SHIFT-JIS')` got 2

meanwhile  `mb_strlen('１２12', 'SHIFT-JIS')` got just 5????

anyone know exactly how to count there strings in byte? please help!!!

Comment: also '12１２' got 6???  O.o

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a number of bytes in a string, use strlen function.

It is a number of characters in a string which is more difficult to get.